Express.js and ytdl-core - downloaded file cannot be open
I'm trying to download music from youtube, Technically it works fine, it downloads the file in shape of mp3, pass it to frontend and save it. File has several kb so it is not empty. However I cannot open it with any player, it is like file is corrupted or so. Any idea why does it happen like this? When I launch it with postman then in response I get player which works and play the sound (if I comment out onProgress functionality).
I tested it on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=487jIOnY-yE
export const downloadVideoFromUrl = async (videoUrl: string, res: Response) => {
  console.log("Processing video URL:", videoUrl);

  if (!ytdl.validateURL(videoUrl)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid YouTube URL");
  }

  try {
    const videoInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(videoUrl);
    const title = videoInfo.videoDetails.title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "_");

    const format = ytdl.chooseFormat(videoInfo.formats, { quality: "highestaudio", filter: "audio" });
    if (!format) {
      throw new Error("No suitable format found");
    }

    res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="${title}.mp3"`);
    res.header("Content-Type", "audio/mp3");
    const contentLength = format.hasOwnProperty("contentLength") ? format.contentLength : null;
    if (contentLength) {
      res.header("Content-Length", contentLength.toString());
    }

    const videoStream = ytdl(videoUrl, { format });
    videoStream.on("progress", (_, downloaded, total) => {
      const progress = (downloaded / total) * 100;
      res.write(`progress:${progress.toFixed(2)}%\n`);
    });

    videoStream
      .pipe(res)
      .on("finish", () => {
        console.log("Download complete");
        res.end();
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("Error during download:", err);
        res.status(500).send("Download failed");
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error fetching video information:", err);
    res.status(500).send("Error fetching video information");
  }
};

And my axios but I don't think here is anything what could cause issue:
axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/download`, {
        params: { url: videoUrl },
        responseType: "blob",
        onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            const percent = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
            progressBar.style.width = percent + "%";
          }
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const disposition = response.headers["content-disposition"];
        let filename = "song.mp3"; // Default filename in case something goes wrong
        if (disposition && disposition.indexOf("attachment") !== -1) {
          const matches = /filename="([^"]*)"/.exec(disposition);
          if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
            filename = matches[1];
          }
        }
        const blob = response.data;

        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename;
        link.click();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        alert("Failed to download video.");
      });


This cannot work. YouTube audio formats aren't MP3, so you have to convert your file before sending it to the client. If you don't know how to do it, I can help with a specific answer... Let me know

@pierpy  No need I managed to convert it to mp3. Thank you so much for hint! I was sure that if I download it as a audio then it already has proper format. Thanks!

If this is solved, @Zirek, please consider answering your own question so future readers can benefit from your solution.
